# Reinitialize child component from parent - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way of reinitializing/ resetting/ refreshing child component form parent in LWC? In the picture, parent component passes the geo coordinates to child and the child is rendered on parent button click. What I am trying to achieve here is to reset the child component when second set of coordinates are passed to the child and the button is clicked again.

[image]

**Parent.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Map">
        <div class="slds-form-element" style="width: 20rem; margin-left: 1rem">
            <lightning-input
                type="number"
                name="latitude"
                step="0.00000001"
                label="Enter latitude: "
                data-element="latitude"
            ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input
                type="number"
                name="longitude"
                step="0.00000001"
                label="Enter longitude: "
                data-element="longitude"
            ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button
                variant="brand"
                label="Show Map"
                onclick={handleClick}
                class="slds-m-left_x-medium slds-align_absolute-center"
                style="margin-top: 1rem; width: 12rem"
            ></lightning-button>
        </div>
        <template if:true={showMap}>
            <c-child
                location-coordinates={coordinates}
            ></c-child>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Parent.js**

```
handleClick(evt) {
        const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')].reduce(
            (validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
                inputCmp.value === '' || inputCmp.value === 'undefined'
                    ? inputCmp.setCustomValidity('Please complete this field')
                    : inputCmp.setCustomValidity('');
                inputCmp.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
            },
            true
        );
        if (allValid) {
            let coordinates = [];
            coordinates.push(this.template.querySelector('[data-element="latitude"]').value);
            coordinates.push(this.template.querySelector('[data-element="longitude"]').value);
            this.coordinates = coordinates;
            this.showMap = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is not with the data passing.

**Child.html**

```
<template>
    {locationCoordinates} <!-- Displays updated coordinates -->
    <div class="map-container" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

The problem is I am using an API to construct the map which renders in a DIV element. Since the map is already constructed in the DIV, it won't let me reconstruct it in the same DIV again. DOM APIS like document.createElement('elementName') or element.appendChild(element) doesn't work and I don't have any intensions of using them either to construct the consecutive maps.

Comment: what have you tried? re-setting variables of a child component is something trivial, are you stuck somewhere? Could you update your post with a minimal viable code sample?

Comment: Please [edit] to add at least the parent's template detail, the child component's API property details and the code in the parent you have for passing the coordinate inputs to the child (the code that does the update to the tracked properties you use to set the child's properties in the parent template when the inputs change).

Comment: The problem is I am using an API to construct the map which renders in a DIV element. Since the map is already constructed in the DIV, it won't let me reconstruct it in the same DIV again. DOM APIS like document.createElement('elementName') or element.appendChild(element) doesn't work and I don't have any intensions of using it either.

Comment: then, you can just unrender/remove the element and reconstruct as you would in javascript.